# Installing Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I installed android eclipse galileo, and also downloaded android SDK. while installing AD`, I chose

```
Help->install new software->Add
```

I enter android and the location as https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ but I don't see any package names etc. in the available-software dialog (I am supposed to see 'developer tools', correct?).

I tried with http instead of https, but still the box is empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sometimes have the same problem but it's only a eclipse bug. A work around would be to resize the dialog. Maybe this could help you too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're using Ubuntu Karmic, there's a change in the GTK libs that breaks buttons in Eclipse.  There's a workaround at http://blog.export.be/2009/10/fixing-eclipse-for-ubuntu-karmic-koala-9-10/