# Installing Android

Tags: android, installation

I am having problems installing Android and I would really appreciate your help. My problem is similar to the thread

[Installing Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935659/installing-android-sdk)

howeve it seems there people believe it is a problem of Eclipse. It actually is not since when I run the Android SDK Manager(independent from Eclipse at all) the program cant find anything on the repository  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

Can anyone tell me what can I do? have they moved? that URL in a browser says 404 error!

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be a firewall issue too. if you work in a big company with high network security, most of the ports closed etc, your android avd might be blocked...
if you work at home, switch the firewall off and give it a go!

Comment: good, I'm glad it helped you. please mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use http if https isn't working. It's not safe, but it works.

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

There's a manual option to install adt pluings too: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

But it seems like something has changed at google or is offline

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had probelms with the ADT plugging too but in the end could download it. the manual option seems to be for that. now the problem is the "platforms and other components" (there is no manual option for that) . In http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html the problem is not the step 3  but the step 4. Help please